# Sharepoint 2010 server running stand alone, how to add domain accounts to it for auth?

Tags: active-directory, user-profile

I have a SharePoint server that is not running on our primary domain. I would like the users to come from AD on our primary domain.

so users can login with their [domain][account].

I would also like the user fields when creating site collections and setting permissions to have AD lookup domain accounts.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will need to be a member of that domain in order to be able access the user store and to be able to authenticate the user information supplied.